# Deleted items are still in myAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying this multiple time with what solutions i found on stackoverflow, however I still get deleted items from firebase storage even though i manually delete it from the console.

I don't want delete button on my apps to allow user to delete the uploaded items. Is it myAdapter are not refresh as i delete the items from console?

```js
package com.aiman;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ShowImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //recyclerview object

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;    //adapter object
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;    //database reference
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;    //progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;    //list to hold all the uploaded images

    private List<Upload> uploads;

    
    //new empty constructor
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    //empty constructor
    public class SampleRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_images);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(uploads);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SampleRecycler()); //initialize empty constructor


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        uploads = new ArrayList<>();

        //displaying progress dialog while fetching images
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //adding an event listener to fetch values
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //dismissing the progress dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //iterating through all the values in database
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected to database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    uploads.add(upload);
                    //uploads.notify();
                    //uploads.removeAll(uploads);

                }
                //creating adapter
                adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), uploads);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

```js
package com.aiman;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Upload> uploads;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    //empty adapter constructor
    public MyAdapter(List<Upload> uploads){
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        this.uploads = uploads;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_images, parent, false);
                //.inflate(R.layout.layout_images, null, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
        //uploads.remove(position);
        Upload upload = uploads.get(position);

        holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());

        Glide.with(context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
        //uploads.remove(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return uploads.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry with the code insertion, I just sign up stackoverflow and have no idea how the code insertion works.. above codes is in one file.

Comment: your code is not complete, please put your full code or write the complete scenario to let us help you

Comment: I already edited the codes above, try have a look. ask me if you need additional info about the app. thanks in advanced. cheers